# Terraform aws task definition Container.image contains invalid characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'M developing an aws infrastucture with terraform,

1.-I create a frontend repo

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "frontend" { name = "${var.env}-frontend" }
```

2.-I create a task-definition

> ```
> resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "mambaml" {
>     family                = "${var.env}-mambaml-service"
>     container_definitions = "${file("task-definitions/service.json")}"
>     ....
> }
> ```

3.-service.json file

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "name": "frontend",
>         "image": "${aws_ecr_repository.frontend.repository_url}:latest",
>         "cpu": 1,
>         "memory": 256,
>         "essential": true,
>         "portMappings": [
>           {
>             "containerPort": 80,
>             "hostPort": 80
>           }
>         ]
>       },
> ]
> ```

After that I'm reciving the error

> "ClientException: Container.image contains invalid characters. status
>   code: 400, request id: 46e50fc0-71d9-4b15-b029-ecd9c91d59eb"

This is the ouput for 
`$aws_ecr_repository.frontend.repository_url`

-111111111.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/production-frontend

¿Any idea?

Comment: can you post `task-definitions/service.json`, seems like not passing the correct container name

Comment: or how set the container name in service.json

Comment: Can you remove the last `,` in the service.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution

Data field for resource to consume

```
data "template_file" "app" {
  template = file("terraform/templates/app.json")
  vars = {
    tf_env = "${terraform.workspace}"
    }
  }
```

*JSON CODE BELOW

```
[
  {
    "name": "app",
    "image": "image",
    "cpu": 1024,
    "memory": 2048,
    "networkMode": "vpc",
    "environment": [
            {"name": "PNI_API_HOSTNAME", "value": "app.${tf_env}.com"},
            {"name": "NODE_ENV", "value": "${tf_env}"}
        ],
    "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "app",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
    },
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 3000,
        "hostPort": 3000
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

doing the above allows you to have variables in JSON since JSON won't let you add them in without defining it beforehand.